# UI grid - footer custom aggregation

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I have a UI-Grid in my page and i need to create a footer row to aggregate values.

But in some cases, the value of the footer column is the sum of this column, divided by sum of another column, minus the AVG of the other column.

In the code bellow, for example, the custom footer needs to show the (sum of custom column / AVG age column) + max of the age for max column.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','uiGridConstants', '$http', function ($scope, uiGridConstants, $http) {
var data = [];

$scope.gridOptions = {
    showGridFooter: true,
    showColumnFooter: true,
    enableFiltering: true,
    columnDefs: [
        { field: 'name', width: '13%' },
        { field: 'address.street',aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.sum, width: '13%' },
        { field: 'age', aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.avg, aggregationHideLabel: true, width: '13%' },
        { name: 'ageMin', field: 'age', aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.min, width: '13%', displayName: 'Age for min' },
        { name: 'ageMax', field: 'age', aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.max, width: '13%', displayName: 'Age for max' },
        { name: 'customCellTemplate', field: 'age', width: '14%', footerCellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" style="background-color: Red;color: White">custom template</div>' },
        { name: 'registered', field: 'registered', width: '20%', cellFilter: 'date', footerCellFilter: 'date', aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.max }
    ],
    data: data,
    onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
            $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    }
};

$http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/500_complex.json')
  .success(function(data) {
    data.forEach( function(row) {
      row.registered = Date.parse(row.registered);
    });
    $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
  });
}]);
```

```css
.grid {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/csv.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/pdfmake.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid"></div>
</div>


    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'ts possible to do it?